# VertexInComponent not working properly on edgless graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs

**Bug introduced in 12.1 and persisting through 12.3.1** 
Note: The 3rd argument of `VertexInComponent` was introduced in 12.1.

---

The code

```
VertexInComponent[
    Graph[{v1, v2}, {v1 \[DirectedEdge] v2}], v1, {1}]
```

gives the correct answer `{}`, as there are no edges going into `v1`. The code

```
VertexInComponent[Graph[{v1, v2}, {}], v1, {1}]
```

obtained by removing the only edge from the previous line, gives the wrong answer `{v1}`. I think `VertexInComponent` doesn't behave properly on graphs with no edges.

I am using Mathematica 12.2.0.

Comment: Please do report this to Wolfram Support. It seems to me that this is a bug. I can reproduce it in M12.3 as well. Do not that the empty graph is effectively "undirected", so there's a difference there as well, but this doesn't quite explain how the problem occurs.

Comment: this bug is fixed in version 13.0.0.